# Clock / timer activated 2 second voltage timer for wiper motor project

Tags: motor, clock, timer, 12v, delay

Ok, I need a 12 volt voltage timer using clock or timer for a wiper motor. I am working on a project in my garage. Simply put, I am wanting to use a wiper motor that will open and close a spring held door after approx 2-5 seconds. This is achieved by letting the wiper motor circulate one time. The wiper motor was selected because of its "park" feature, allowing the motor to maintain power until back to original position and then shuts off. So all I need is a circuit that can apply 12 volts for just 1-2 seconds to essentially "bump" the motor out of "park" and then let the wiper motor do the rest. I am wanting this to happen automatically at two separate times during the day exactly 12 hours apart. For example at 6am and 6pm. The "rub" to this question is that the motor draws approx 5-10 amps during operation meaning the timer would have to allow for this... I think. These wiper motors are used in all kinds of neat applications so I think it is very plausible. I have plenty of experience fixing electronics, just not very experienced building them. So, as simple as possible is appreciated. Is this possible? (I just found a feeder timer for a deer corn feeder that works off of sunrise then again 12 hours later. This is basically what I am looking for but for inside) If no answer I may just try to go buy one of those and try to re wire it to work off a clock or something and see if it will stand up to the amperage) Thanks in advance to all that reply.

Comment: Your mention of the "park" feature implies you already have some circuit attached to your motor. Is that true or do you have just the standalone DC wiper motor? If you're not sure, post a picture of it.

Comment: Also, where is your power coming from? Do you already have a 12VDC source?

Answer (score 1):

I take it that the motor has at least three wires: 12V power and ground, and a third one that signals it to do a cycle? So you'll need the main power to stay on until the end of the cycle (or just all the time), but the control signal needs to end before the cycle finishes so that it doesn't immediately cycle again. The control wire should only need a tiny current, so the timer circuit doesn't need to be a high-amperage one.

Timing an interval of 12 hours with an analogue solution like a 555 chip would be very inaccurate. The easiest working solution would be to get a cheap digital timer for mains-powered appliances, one that lets you program it with 1-second accuracy. Connect a little 12V power source to it (just for the control signal - the beefy main supply would be on all the time) and program it to go on for just one second. It might also come in the form of a digital timer for aquarium lighting or similar applications, and those might even have direct 12V signal outputs.

A more sophisticated solution (in some ways) would be to use an Arduino, and program it to count enough 1-second intervals to result in 12 hours. Namely, 43199 seconds off and then 1 second on. It would also need a transistor circuit to convert the 5V signal to 12V (that could be just 1 resistor and 1 transistor, for example). If that amount of programming and electronics isn't too much for you, you could also get a real-time clock module for it ([$2 on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/DS3231-AT24C32-IIC-module-precision-Real-time-clock-module-memory-module-Arduino-/400503978923?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5d3fe5bbab)) so that the activation time is based on actual wall clock time instead of just a 12-hour delay from whatever time it was powered on.

On the other hand, a duct-tape-grade solution could have a certain charm as well: rigging a wire to be touched by the hour hand of a mechanical clock... but even this would require something like a 555-based circuit that shortens the duration of the pulse to about 1 second, since the hour hand moves away so slowly :-)